# Bizarre C++ code, trying to decipher

Tags: java, c++

I am converting some C++ code into Java, and making it easier to understand.

Here is the Line:

```
Out[i] = (Sum += Tap[TapPtr++] = Inp[i]);
```

Translating into Java and making it easier to understand, I have written:

```
Tap[TapPtr++] = Inp[i];
Sum = Sum + Inp[i];
```

Should the next line be

```
Out[i] =  Sum;
```

or should it be

```
Out[i] = Inp[i];
```

Regards,
Howard

Comment: You should increment `TapPtr` only **once**.

Comment: I would recommend not being so liberal with your question tags.

Comment: I would learn Java coding standards.  https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html.   Read the C++ precedence rules.

Comment: Willem Van Onsem, ok, edited for that.

Comment: It's `Out[i] = Sum;` - the value of an assignment expression is always the value post-assignment of the variable that was updated.  This information is certainly available in the C++ documentation.

Comment: What are the types of `Inp`, `Tap`, `Sum`, and `Out`?

Comment: It's `Out[i] = Sum`.   However, the conversion of `Sum += ...` to `Sum = Sum + ...` may not be valid in Java, depending on the type of `Tap`.

Comment: For the record it should be mentioned that this is one utterly horrible line of C++ and someone should be punished for writing it. Just because you *can* mash two dozen things into a single line doesn’t mean you *should*.

Comment: sum is double.   Inp , Out, and Tap are arrays of double.     TapPtr and i are integer

Comment: besc, yes I thought it was one of many horrible lines of code that this brilliant guy had written.  I think if the unnecessary parenthesis were omitted, it would have been a little more obvious.  The parenthesis made me think it was somehow calculating something special inside.  I think the labor to  maintain software is far more expensive than the cost of the initial computer system.  I pride myself on writing easy to understand code, though many years ago I did once use a goto statement as an easy out of a complex situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify the types, so I'm going to assume that these are all builtin C++ types, specifically arithmetic types (either integer type or a floating point type). If it is a user defined type, I can't guarantee that anything I say below still applies.

`T& lhs.operator=(T& rhs)` is the copy assignment operator (it could also be a move assignment, but not in this case). The (canonical) copy assignment operator takes a reference to the `rhs` as a parameter, copies the data into the `lhs`, and returns a reference to `lfs`.

`T& lhs.operator++(int)` is the increment operator (note the `int`, this is what separates a postfix from a prefix increment operator). While `T&` is the canonical return type for most builtin types, it is common for user defined types to return `T`. Either way, the postfix increment operator increases the value of `lhs` but returns the original value.

`T& lhs.operator+=(T& rhs)` is the compound addition assignment operator. It is equivalent to the expression `lhs=lhs+rhs` except that `lhs` gets evaluated only once.

So the equivalent not confusing code to

```
Out[i] = (Sum += Tap[TapPtr++] = Inp[i]);
```

would be

```
{
  auto tempTapPtr=TapPtr;
  ++TapPtr;
  Tap[tempTapPtr]=Inp[i];
  Sum+=Tap[tempTapPtr];
}
Out[i]=Sum;
```

As you can see, the correct last line in your Java code should be `Out[i]=Sum;` but unless the types are not the builtin arithmetic types, the `Out[i]=Inp[i]` is functionally equivalent. Also, the second line of your Java code is incorrect. It should be `Sum=Sum+Tap[TapPtr-1];` but like with the last line, is functionally equivalent to what you wrote.

Comment: sum is double. Inp , Out, and Tap are arrays of double. TapPtr and i are integer

Comment: Thanks. Since these are built-in types, I don't need to change anything about the meat of the answer. I'll keep the warning about user defined types so that my answer stays general.